# generics typecasting issue with code

Tags: java, generics

I get the class cast issue at line 4 in the following code. How do I cast from generic Class to  type ABC . Ignore and enlighten me if I am doing something wrong.

```
@Override
public ABC<INPUT> getCode()
{
  return getInputCode(); -- This returns type Class which is Class<? extends ABC<INPUT>>
}
;


protected Class<? extends ABC<INPUT>> getInputCode()
{
return (Class)SomeSerialization.class;
}

class SomeSerialaization implements ABC,Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1276372676372L;
 //logic
}
```

Comment: `Ignore and enlighten me`... I'm pretty sure I can only pick one.

Comment: Please show us the signature of `getInputCode()` directly.

Comment: @LouisWasserman i have edited.. let me know if this is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overridden method's signature tells you to return an object of type ABC but what is actually returned is of type Class.

Return an object of ABC if you want to stick to overridden method's interface.

Comment: As you can see that is an overridden method and I cannot change the return type to Class.

Comment: In that case, what you are returning is wrong.. what you return from your code is reference of Class type.. and your "overridden" method signature want to return Object of type ABC<INPUT>.
Consider writing new method for this.

Comment: Thanks Raman, this has helped.. I am returning an object now.

Answer (score 0):

You can *try* to instantiate an instance of a type represented by a `Class` object by calling `Class.newInstance()`.  This will only work with classes with simple no-arg default constructors.  There is no fully general way to instantiate a `Class`, because not all classes *can* be instantiated.